# Docker Mounted Volumes to facilitate development

Tags: docker, bind, mount, volumes

I'm using Docker Desktop on a Windows Enterprise 11 host machine to copy java source files from the host to an docker image; I then want to run the image in a container where the java source files from the image can be made available (and persisted) in a mounted host directory (volume), super easy use case, but its not working.

1. The Dockerfile makes the "code-in-container" directory (for image) and copies java source files and sub-directories from "code-on-host" (local host) to "code-in-container" (on the image), a text file is also copied to "code-in-container", the image is built on a Linux Alpine base image.

   ```docker
   FROM alpine:latest
   RUN mkdir -p /code-in-container
   COPY /code-on-host /code-in-container/
   COPY file-on-host.txt /code-in-container
   ```
2. The docker-compose creates a service based on the Dockerfile referenced (and outlined above), sets up port forwarding from host -> container, and then creates a binding mount called "some-host-directory" (where the ./ provides the context of where "some-host-directory" should be created on the host, this is based on where the compose-file and Dockerfile are hosted), the compose-file then maps the bind mount to the "/code-in-container" directory within the running container (image). The stdin_open and tty is used to keep the container running so the mount can be established and I can access the shell of the running container.

host directory

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  my_app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    volumes:
      - ./some-host-directory:/code-in-container
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

I use `docker compose up -d` to build image and run it in a docker container, the "code-on-host" contains source files and sub-directories, however, when the image is built and run the "some-host-directory" and "code-in-container" directories are empty.

When I build just the docker image using

```shell
docker build -t my-dev-image:1.0 .
```

(which uses the Dockerfile from the current folder in terminal) and then run the the image using

```shell
docker run -d my-dev-image:1.0
```

where I added `CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]` to keep the container running when its run, then, I can see the "code-in-container" directory available in the container when I access the running containers shell using

```shell
docker exec -it <container_id/bin/sh> /bin/sh
```

Can anyone help explain what I'm missing when I run the "docker inspect <container_id>" I see the following in the "Mount" section:

```
    "Mounts": [
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "C:\\PathTo\\Host\\Directory\\code-on-host",
            "Destination": "/code-in-container",
            "Mode": "rw",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        }
    ],
```

But I don't see a reference to a "Type": "volume", unsure if that is significant, but would expect a volume reference to exist.

Cheers.

I have tried build the just the image from Dockerfile and running that image in Docker Desktop, I have tried using docker-compose to build the image and mount the image directory to the host directory specified as a volume in docker-compose file. Again all to no avail. I'm wondering if the challenge is because the image is built and used locally, and it should be in a docker image repository and accessed that way from the docker-compose file. I also tried to use a Windows Linux Subsystem to generate the image and run it using a docker-compose file.

Comment: Would installing Java on your host system be easier than the work you described here?  Remember that you have to recompile and restart your application whenever you make a code change anyways; `docker-compose build && docker-compose up -d` is not much more work than `./gradlew build && ./gradlew bootRun` for example, and correspondingly I probably wouldn't try to force Docker into this setup.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was under the impression that this was a standard use case for docker, have files that need to be accessed by another person be included in the image when its generated and then whoever runs that image in a container and has a bind mount setup can then see the files from the image on their local host machine; the challenge seems to be that if you enable "use WSL 2 based engine", the mount is done in the context of the Linux distro that comes with WSL, or it could the image needs to be uploaded into an Artifactory repo, looking into it a little more

Comment: Docker bind mounts _always_ hide whatever's in the image and replace it with content from the host; you cannot directly use them to make the image editable or see the image content.  For the use case you're describing I'd use an ordinary source-control system like Git and a normal JDK, and not involve Docker at all.